# How to link drawable-xhdpi folder with my drawable-sw720dp?

Tags: android

I have 5 folders in my res/ folder:

drawable-ldpi/

drawable-mdpi/

drawable-hdpi/

drawable-xhdpi/

drawable-sw720dp/

The first 4 folders have 65 images each and I want that my drawable-sw720dp/ has the same images of
drawable-xhdpi/. I can't copy all 65 images of drawable-xhdpi folder beacuse I can't increase the apk size.

I need this because a mdpi tablet by default takes the images from drawable-mdpi folder and this cause
a bad image quality. The use of xhdpi folder dramatically increases the quality of images.

How can I do?

Comment: better no need of folder drawable-sw720dp.

Comment: I've updated the question, look the reason of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [alias resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources) to link the two versions.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not use Alias ​​because in that case I should rename every image in the drawable-xhdpi folder because I have to make them different from those in ldpi mdpi and hdpi folders. This renaming forces me to programmatically manage the images for xhdpi device.

Comment: @VanDir I would say that this is the way to go. You would need to move the current xhdpi images in the default folder, rename them(like adding `_shared` to each name) and then reference those in the two folders like it says in the link above. There is no code involved.

Comment: Wow, now I understand and I believe it is a correct solution. Thank you. Best answer. :)

Comment: @Luksprog can you explain me in detail how to do that..
i am working with a tablet,currently i am using 2 folders drawable-large-xhdpi,drawable-xlarge-hdpi which have same images ..How to make it one folder ? you will be really helpfull for answer.

Comment: @user1920666 First of all, in general drawables should be qualified only by density and not by screen size. The link I provided shows how to alias drawables: put the shared images in the default drawable folder(give them a different name than the name you'll be susing in code); in **each** of the folders you mention make a xml file(which will have the same name in both of the folders, this will be the name used in code); this file will be either a bitmap or ninepatch xml file which will point to the desired shared image from the basic drawable folder.

Comment: I have done that but not working as i desire..
i have images of 1920x1080 reosolution
the image is (1/3) of screen width in 10 inch tablet but 1/2 of width in 7 inch

Comment: @user1920666 Please ask a new question providing more details about what you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419223/using-same-drawable-image-in-two-different-folder-to-support-all-tablets-same-i

Answer (score 1):

since you are going to use images in a generic folder, then its better to place them in drawable-xhdi and then and delete from sw720, so that wheneveer you want a xhdpi 10inch tablet the resources would be first from the generic folder.

However, you might encounter a case where the tablet itself is mdpi, so it would be good to have 2 versions

`drawable-xhdpi-sw720dp` and `drawable-mdpi-sw720dp`

Comment: According to the documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources the correct name of the folders are drawable-sw720dp-xhdpi and drawable-sw720dp-mdpi. The order of the configuration qualifiers is important!