# Using same drawable image in two different folder to support all tablets.(same image (no change)in two folders)

Tags: android, drawable, tablet, android-resources, android-drawable

I want to keep same images in two folders drawable-large-xhdpi and drawable-xlarge-hdpi.
avoiding duplication of images reduces memory How?
I am having images of 1920x1080 resolution
Any usefull answer i am very thankful to all.
(example: if the image is half of screen width , it should be half of the screen in all tablets)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources

Comment: *if the image is half of screen width , it should be half of the screen in all tablets* - You'll need to that in code. You can't use the drawables system for what you want because the `-large`, `-xlarge` identifiers refer to a bucket of dimensions not a specific value like you want.

Comment: if the image is in two different folders drawable-large-xhdpi and drawable-xlarge-hdpi i am getting half in all tablets..
the thing is i dont want to use two folders..
i have 100 images in each folder.

Comment: Again, I'm not sure that would work. I've already said how to make the alias: move the desired image in the drawable folder(and give it a some different name, for example `imagename_shared`). Then in the two layout folders use a bitmap xml (imagename.xml) like this: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/imagename_shared" />'. Make sure your layour folders are the ones the system actually uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep exactly the same image in `drawable-large-xhdpi` and `drawable-xlarge-hdpi` then you apparently do not really understand what these `xhdpi` and `hdpi` selectors stands for, as image cannot be `hdpi` and `xhdpi` at the same time, so your approach is basically wrong. Please read this article to get the picture of how Android manages assets: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

**EDIT**

Here another article that you need to read to understand how Android picks assets and how it falls back in case of lack of such: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch that will help you organize your assets correctly

Comment: Hi  when i am using same drawable in drawable folder image is not fitting.
but when i use same image in these 2 folders i am getting same result in nexus 7 and nexus 10.why ?

Comment: can u suggest me how to do that ? i am taking the images of 1920x1080 resolution

Comment: i suspect you use this drawable with `ImageView` which scales it up. But as I wrote in my answer - read linked article and understand what density thing is and how to deal with it. I also linked another article in my edited answer so you will understand how android falls back if certain asset if missing

Comment: ok thank you for your answer if i get any doubts i will comment here .
i will read now